# How to avoid deletion of Storage/VM when managing Azure Test Drive?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template

I have a scenario where I have a cold instance enabled for an Azure Marketplace App. The ARM template is used to deploy the App. When I try the test drive, it creates a new VM, and after the time ends for the Test Drive, VM is deleted automatically, and for the next test drive, it creates a new VM.

I am running into a problem as each time the VM is deleted, it deletes the docker container deployed to the VM used in the test drive.

I am not finding a solution to avoid permanently deleting the docker container deployed to the VM. Is there any way I could achieve that using Cold instance?

Or do I need to use Hot instance for it?

The machine type used is `Standard_D2ads_v5`. The operating system installed is `18.04-LTS`.

**Update**

I also tested deploying a single HOT instance only, and whenever I request the test drive, my docker container gets deleted, and the VM gets a new IP.

Why is that happening?

Comment: Similar thread: [How to avoid deletion of Storage/VM when managing a Cold Instance in Azure Test Drive?](How to avoid deletion of Storage/VM when managing a Cold Instance in Azure Test Drive?)

Comment: You can keep the Docker container running on the Hot instance by configuring the instance to automatically start the container on boot. This way, when the VM is restarted, the Docker container will be automatically started and continue to run until the VM is shut down or deleted.

Comment: @Sourav I've tried hot instance and the IP changes with each new test drive request and docker contianer us gone. Is there any issue with my configurations?